# how can i retrieve all embedded array values in PHP MONGODB

Tags: php, mongodb

I want to retrieve all places only _id fields for Select box in PHP MONGODB. How can I do this. 
DB structure is:

```
{
    "_id" : "state1",
    "s_name" : "West Bengal",
    "places" : [
        [
            {
                "_id" : "Howra"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "_id" : "Kolkata"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "_id" : "Jalpaiguri"
            }
        ],
        [
           {
                "_id" : "Alipurduar"
           }
        ],
    ]
}
```

how can i write PHPcode here...

```
<select class="form-control input-sm">
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
</select>
```

[image]

Comment: What are you asking actually? If you just return the document then is the array not already there? Is the actual question/issue the fact that the items are all nested inside their own arrays, and are also in documents with an `_id` property as opposed to `[ "Howra", "Kolkata", Jalpaiguri", "Alipurduar" ]`? So it an array like that you are expecting the database to return? Why not just change the array in code? Or better yet fix the data.

Comment: i add a pic of the resultent view

Comment: I think I already said that you want `[ "Howra", "Kolkata", Jalpaiguri", "Alipurduar" ]`. My point is that the data actually **is** there in the document. It's not in the best format, but it is still there. Whilst "possible" to get the server to alter that it is generally easier to **A**: Do the transformation in client code rather than on the server. **B**: Fix the data so it is actually stored the way you want to use it.

Comment: Actually latter i want to add more fields according to perticular places ....like in _id : Howra..subplace1, sublace 2, details....if i want to retrive only this format then can i or not...if yes please share code

Comment: Your question is unclear. All I see is a sample document of how it is stored and a combo box. I'm still really only guessing at the response format you expect to return. Also the only method I know of to get the database to do this is overkill IMHO, and you can just to data manipulation after returning from the database. But it's unclear if you are even asking how to manipulate the data in PHP if necessary. It's a really unclear question. So just trying to advise and hopefully prompt you to make the question clearer. Preferably without adding more images,

Comment: I just wonder why u r not understand this....i simply says for html select box i want all embeded arrays id field which is belongs under places..4 dynamic page ....then how can i.......actually its all district names ...which i want to retrieve for html select box